# Appointments and Reminders for ShellView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

At the moment clients can save reminders to the database specifying Day, Month, Year along with time it should display. The structure is MVVM with caliburns IScreens. I'm thinking of implementing the Background scheduler within the ShellViewModel and I would like to implement a listener and an event trigger when the DateTime has been reached. It should display an appointment prompt with options for "Closing and Snoozing".

I'm wondering how do I implement the listener and the background event triggers

```
public class Appointments
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public int AppointmentId {get; set;}
    public DateTime AppointmentDate {get; set;
}
```

Comment: You mean like starting a timer when the application starts, and on each tick check to see if any of the Appointments or Reminders are due? You could also use an event messaging system for alerting other parts of the application. I'm not sure Caliburn's version of it, but PRISM uses an `EventAggregator` and MVVM Light had a `Messenger` class to accomplish this task.

Comment: Hi Rachel, yes it's a timer basically when it reaches the time specified by the appointments. Example, It's 11:58 am, we have an appointment at 12:00pm it should prompt a popup in 2 mins.